# Scope in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was trying to understand scope in angularjs.

Say while registering a directive in angularjs if we dont provide any scope as the property of the object, what is the scope of the object then?

For example consider the following code:-

```
 app.directive("kid", function() {
 return {
restrict: "E",
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="chore"> {{chore}}'
  };
});
```

Now say if i have 2 elements in my html:-

```
  <kid></kid>
  <kid></kid>
```

So how do above end up sharing the same scope? I am not able to find convincing answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about scope inheritance and isolate scope.

If you **do** declare a scope property on a directive object then the directive has its own isolate scope.

If you **don't** declare a scope property on your directive object the directive inherits the scope of the scope it was instantiated in.

So with your definition of the kid directive that doesn't declare an isolate scope the kid directives in the code example below both inherit the scope of the controller that they are instantiated in.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <kid></kid>
     <kid></kid> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, As you didn't declared any `scope` option of directive, it will share the same scope.

Here is [**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qEiDrZcQ2Arixz0HBTow?p=preview)

**Now come to the point, what is scope object?**

`scope` object in Angular is nothing having context information and that will available on `html`, can also be utilized to provide two way binding. Basically scope is binded with some controller.

When things comes to directive `scope`, if you didn't mention `scope` property inside directive, that means directive shares the scope of the controller where the directive element has been placed.

To make them treated as a different `scope` for each directive you could create an an directive with an isolated scope, which can be defined using `scope: {}` inside a directive, when you define a `scope: {}` inside a directive, it creates an isolated child scope which is not prototypically inherited from the parent scope using `$scope.$new(true)` method.

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tRb1V7AR97J6jbNtPpZP?p=preview) with isolated scope

Comment: It seems like you understand isolate scopes as a concept but your English leaves room for vast misinterpretation. Maybe reword this a bit more carefully.

Comment: I did start to edit your answer but found myself rewriting it completely so I just added an answer of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is an object that refers to the application model. It is an execution context for expressions. Scopes are arranged in hierarchical structure which mimic the DOM structure of the application. Scopes can watch expressions and propagate events.

**Scope characteristics**

1. Scopes provide APIs ($watch) to[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEkVF.png) observe model mutations.
2. Scopes provide APIs ($apply) to propagate any model changes through
   the system into the view from outside of the “Angular realm”
   (controllers, services, Angular event handlers).
3. Scopes provide context against which expressions are evaluated.

For example {{username}} expression is meaningless, unless it is evaluated against a specific scope which defines the username property.Scope is the glue between application controller and the view.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEkVF.png]